# PyQt4: Hide widget and resize window

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I'm working with several widgets but the solution just won't come out. What I have is a series of buttons in series of `QHBoxLayouts`. Some buttons are hidden by default, but they will appear when needed. To solve space issues, all buttons have a minimum and maximum size so they always look well packed. Also I have a `QTextEdit`, visible by default, which is in a `QVBoxLayout` with the `QHBoxLayout` that hold the buttons

So the problem is this: When I hide the `QTextEdit` and show the other buttons, the window won't resize. 
After searching I found that using `self.ui.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetFixedSize)` will do the trick, but the problem is that it takes the maximum size from all widgets, therefore I end a huge window. Doing `self.ui.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)` won't resize the window

I already tried using `self.ui.resize(0,0)`, and when doing a `self.ui.layout().update()` I got False (which I find odd, http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qlayout.html#activate), and also tried to override `sizeHint()` but it keeps using the max size for all widgets.

Is there a way to resize the window and while taking care of the min and max size of a widget?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the code, or at least a snippet? I think it would be easier to understand and try to diagnose this problem if I could see it in action.

Comment: Since I'm using the uic module, and the original source code has many dependences, I'm posting the relevant Window code http://pastebin.com/f1544ffdb (which is very little) and the uic file http://pastebin.com/f65684099 . Also some screenshots http://www.flickr.com/photos/21252852@N06/sets/72157623339593841/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was quite lame... Just needed to change the `QVBoxLayout` for a `QGridLayout` and use `self.ui.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetFixedSize)`

Comment: You could accept your answer, so that your question will not show up in "unanswered questions" list.